# jQuery ajax scope and dom manipulation

Tags: jquery, dom, scope

I have a js file (called in the page header) that contains some code that is run on every page of a CMS called admin.js. It contains some code for handling file uploads with a jQuery file upload plugin.

I am building a widget system in the CMS. It uses bootstrap modals. If I put the file upload form in the modal, the file upload works fine, but if I load the form with ajax in the modal, the file upload plugin does not fire.

The code for the modal and ajax is something like this:

```
$('#widget').on('show', function (event) {
    var page_id = $('#widget').data('modal').options.page_id;
    var widget_id = $('#widget').data('modal').options.widget_id;
    $.ajax({
        url: ADMIN_INCLUDES_URL + 'widget/widget.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: {
            'page_id': page_id,
            'widget_id': widget_id,
            'action': 'form'
        },
        success: function(r){
            $('#widget').html(r);
        }
    });
});
```

I don't want to duplicate the file upload js code. I'm using .on() and I've also tried .live() but neither work?

Comment: We should see your form markup, and your file upload plugin as well.

Comment: try to place the event on some parent like this:
$('some_parent').on('click', 'element', function(){});

Comment: I tried putting it into a fiddle but it's difficult to extract.

Demo here:     cms.bidibo.co.uk/admin

email: so@so.com
pass: password

Go to pages > edit pages > click edit on a widget

Comment: I also tried just adding this content to the modal and the ajax response: <div class="click">Click Me</div>. And this js in the admin.js file.

    $('.click').on('click', function(){
       console.log('clicked');
    });

It works in the modal but not in the ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to use a container that is present before any ajax calls and bind the dynamic elements to that

e.g - this will bind a click event to any .click element now and in the future that is a child of #widget

```
$('#widget').on('click', '.click', function(){ console.log('clicked');});
```